# Google Chrome not opening after install

Tags: google-chrome, google

When I try to open Google Chrome from folder using home: *filesystem* -> *opt* -> *chrome* and double-click on chrome, it complains:

```
could not display "/opt/google/chrome/chrome"
There is no application installed for shared library files. 
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

And when I say yes, it just gives me a window without any name of application. I had to cancel.

When I went to terminal and cd to `/opt/google/chrome/` and run `nohup ./chrome &` then it works.

Has anyone had this problem and is there anyway to resolve this opening issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have resolved my problem.  I have gone to `Dash Home` by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> key  and searched for Google and when I opened (by double-click) it opened successfully.